# simpledialog2, styles customization

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have an app which has several types of popups, so each one should has its own CSS styles, is there a way to do this, to give a simpledialog2 a custom CSS styles but not to all of the dialogs in the app?
I tried with:

`$("<div>").simpledialog2({
....
}).attr('class', 'someClass');`

I have tried also with:

```
$("#myElement").simpledialog2({....,buttons : {   'Aceptar': {     click: function () { 
},     icon: ""    }   }});
```

But it does not worked.

I need to have buttons in the popup so I better not use "blankContent" because it does not let to close the popup only when pressing the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

To close the popup, you just have to have a link with rel='close' as given in the documentation http://dev.jtsage.com/jQM-SimpleDialog/demos2/blankin.html

```
<!--NOTE: blankContent is set to TRUE, and the content goes IN the div. -->
<div id="inlinecontent" style="display:none" 
  data-options='{"mode":"blank","headerText":"Yo","headerClose":true,"blankContent":true}'>

    <ul data-role='listview'><li>Some</li><li>List</li><li>Items</li></ul>
    <a rel='close' data-role='button' href='#'>Close</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can use "theme" value in the simpledialog2's definition, as  `theme: "d"`, then I can change its CSS style.